# PHP extract part from array keeping previous keys

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have the array with specific keys. I want to get the first 5 array elements. I use `array_splice()`. All OK, but keys in the new array is 0, 1, 2, 3 ,4. And I want to keep the previous array keys. I can do it with `foreach`, but i am finding the elegant method.
My code:

```
$levels = array('a' => 1, 'b' =>2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 6);
$levels = array_splice($levels, 5);
```

Thank you in advance. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) with `$preserve_keys` set to `true`.

Answer (score 14):

With [array_**sl**ice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), the original array is not modified:

```
$levels = array('a' => 1, 'b' =>2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 6);
$firstLevels = array_slice($levels, 0, 5, true);
// count($levels) is 6, count($firstLevels) 5
```